# Firebase Upload a file with fragment in MainActivity

Tags: android-studio, file-upload, firebase-storage, android-fragmentactivity

I am developing an app with android studio, the app has a main activity, and has 3 fragments included with a Navigation view controller. Now what I'm trying to do is to implement a system in one of the fragment so that when the user clicks on one button, the gallery intent shows up and then the selected image displays in an image view, and then there is one button to uplaod the image to firebase storage.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I did a little research on hiw to do it, it worked fine if the functions where in the main activity, but when I tried to implement the same thing in the fragment where it is supposed to be, the app just build do and everything, but when it launches and I happen to click on the chose image button it craches

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post what you tried to do and what errors you got using code samples, logs, etc. in the question. Refer to this guide for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.